# How can I debug this validation error when I cannot seem to reproduce it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I built a sign up form on my website that has been (seemingly) randomly erroring for about 3% of my users (just an estimate).  The error disallows the user from signing up for my service, and they often have to call the office so that we can manually add them as a new customer.  This costs us quite a bit of time on the phone, and potentially costs us business for those users that decide not to call in, and instead go to a competitor.

I have tried debugging this many times, and even rebuilt the sign up system this past year out of frustration, but I am still encountering the bug.  *I just don't have any more ideas on how to debug it, and was hoping someone had an idea about a new way to test why this might be happening (or force the error to happen for me), or a better way of handling it.*

*I tried to trim down my code to just include the relevant pieces (they are long files), so please let me know if there is something else I need to include

**EDIT:** @Greg Watters suggested that I write shared functions which multiple 'blur' handlers can use to manage the state for multiple inputs (like student password and confirm student password).  I will be trying that next, but if anyone else has additional ideas, I am all ears.  **UPDATE** This has no change on the issue

**EDIT2** I created an email which allows me to see which inputs are marked as "invalid" right after the user clicks submit on the form, but prior to actual button firing.  The inputs that were marked "invalid" were seemingly random

**EDIT 3** A friend suggested that it might be an autofill issue.  Because I have triggered the validation with a blur event, and the autocomplete may not trigger this event.  I have added redundant validation on the submission button to check if this may fix the problem

**How the sign up form and validation work**

- All required inputs start with a class of "invalid"
- When a user fills in the input, I validate it using js, and if everything is okay, I remove the class "invalid".  If it is not validated, I display an error below the input, highlight the input in red, and keep the class "invalid"
- Once the user presses "submit", I loop through every input on the form and check for a class of "invalid".  If any input still contains the class "invalid", I display a message to fix the errors at the bottom of the form and highlight the relevant inputs in red.  If no inputs contain the class "invalid", the form submits.

**What happens during the error**

- User fills out each required input, and no validation errors appear.  When I speak with them on the phone live during this process, every single person is *positive* they have filled out the form with valid information and have filled in all required inputs
- User clicks submit, and an error appears at the bottom of the form asking them to fix errors, but no inputs are highlighted red, and no extra input errors are displayed.

**Form Validation**

```
$("#signUp-submit").live("click", function() {
    $(".signUpError").empty();
    var error = false;
    $(".signUpTextbox").each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("invalid")) {
            $(".signUpError").text('Please correct errors');
            $(".invalid").css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:575}, 'slow');
            error = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (error == false) {
        var customerType = $("#signUp-customerType").val();
        var school = $("#signUp-school").val();
        var studentEmail = $("#signUp-studentEmail").val();
        var studentFirstName = $("#signUp-studentFirstName").val();
        var studentLastName = $("#signUp-studentLastName").val();
        var studentPhone = $("#signUp-studentPhone").val();
        var studentPhoneCarrier = $("#signUp-studentPhoneCarrier").val();
        var studentAddress1 = $("#signUp-studentAddress1").val();
        var studentAddress2 = $("#signUp-studentAddress2").val();
        var parentEmail = $("#signUp-parentEmail").val();
        var parentAddress1 = $("#signUp-parentAddress1").val();
        var parentAddress2 = $("#signUp-parentAddress2").val();
        var parentCity = $("#signUp-parentCity").val();
        var parentState = $("#signUp-parentState").val();
        var parentZip = $("#signUp-parentZip").val();
        var parentPhone = $("#signUp-parentPhone").val();
        var referral = $("#signUp-referral").val();

        if (customerType == "student") {
            var studentPassword = $("#signUp-studentPassword").val();
        }
        else if (customerType == "parent") {
            var parentPassword = $("#signUp-parentPassword").val();
            var parentFirstName = $("#signUp-parentFirstName").val();
            var parentLastName = $("#signUp-parentLastName").val();
        }

        $(".footerSignUpContent").html('<div class = "loadingAnimationFooter" id = "loadingAnimation-FooterSignUp"></div>');

        $.post(
                'ajax/signUp.php', 
            {
                'customerType': customerType,
                'school': school,
                'studentEmail': studentEmail,
                'studentPassword': studentPassword,
                'studentFirstName': studentFirstName,
                'studentLastName': studentLastName,
                'studentPhone': studentPhone,
                'studentPhoneCarrier': studentPhoneCarrier,
                'studentAddress1': studentAddress1,
                'studentAddress2': studentAddress2,
                'parentAddress1': parentAddress1,
                'parentAddress2': parentAddress2,
                'parentCity': parentCity,
                'parentState': parentState,
                'parentZip': parentZip,
                'parentPassword': parentPassword,
                'parentFirstName': parentFirstName,
                'parentLastName': parentLastName,
                'parentEmail': parentEmail,
                'parentPhone': parentPhone,
                'referral': referral
            },
            function (response) {
                $("#footerTitle-SignUp").html("Thanks!");
                $(".footerSignUpContent").html(response);
            }
        );
    }
})
```

**Individual input validations**

```
$("#signUp-studentEmail").live("blur", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
    var studentEmail = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(studentEmail != "") {
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        if(!emailReg.test($(this).val())) {
            $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Please enter a valid email");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
        }
        else {
            $.post(
                'ajax/signUpValidateEmail.php', 
                {
                    'email': studentEmail
                },
                function (response) {
                    $("#signUp-studentEmail").closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").html(response);
                    var notValid = $("#signUpValidateEmail").val();
                    if (notValid == 0) {
                        $("#signUp-studentEmailRepeat").addClass("invalid");
                        $("#signUp-studentEmailRepeat").closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
                        $("#signUp-studentEmailRepeat").css("background-color", "white");
                        var studentEmailRepeat = $("#signUp-studentEmailRepeat").val();
                        if (studentEmail != studentEmailRepeat) {
                            $("#signUp-studentEmailRepeat").closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Emails do not match");
                            $("#signUp-studentEmailRepeat").css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#signUp-studentEmailRepeat").removeClass("invalid");
                        }
                        $("#signUp-studentEmail").removeClass("invalid");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#signUp-studentEmail").css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#signUp-studentEmail").css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-studentEmailRepeat").live("blur", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
    var studentEmailRepeat = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(studentEmailRepeat != "") {
        var studentEmail = $("#signUp-studentEmail").val();
        if (studentEmail != studentEmailRepeat) {
            $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Emails do not match");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("invalid");
        }
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-parentEmail").live("blur", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
    var parentEmail = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(parentEmail != "") {
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        if(!emailReg.test($(this).val())) {
            $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Please enter a valid email");
            $("#signUp-parentEmail").css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
        }
        else {
            $("#signUp-parentEmailRepeat").addClass("invalid");
            $("#signUp-parentEmailRepeat").closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
            $("#signUp-parentEmailRepeat").css("background-color", "white");
            var parentEmailRepeat = $("#signUp-parentEmailRepeat").val();
            if (parentEmail != parentEmailRepeat) {
                $("#signUp-parentEmailRepeat").closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Emails do not match");
                $("#signUp-parentEmailRepeat").css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
            }
            $(this).removeClass("invalid");
        }
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-parentEmailRepeat").live("blur", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
    var parentEmailRepeat = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(parentEmailRepeat != "") {
        var parentEmail = $("#signUp-parentEmail").val();
        if (parentEmail != parentEmailRepeat) {
            $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Emails do not match");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("invalid");
        }
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-studentFirstName").live("blur", function() {
    var studentFirstName = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(studentFirstName != "") {
        $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-studentLastName").live("blur", function() {
    var studentLastName = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(studentLastName != "") {
        $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-studentPhone").live("blur", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
    var studentPhone = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(studentPhone != "") {
        var phoneReg = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
        if(!phoneReg.test($(this).val())) {
            $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Please enter a valid phone number");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("invalid");
        }
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-studentAddress1").live("blur", function() {
    var studentAddress = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(studentAddress != "") {
        $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-parentAddress1").live("blur", function() {
    var parentAddress1 = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(parentAddress1 != "") {
        $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-parentCity").live("blur", function() {
    var parentCity = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(parentCity != "") {
        $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-parentState").live("blur", function() {
    var parentState = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(parentState != "") {
        $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-parentZip").live("blur", function() {
    var parentZip = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(parentZip != "") {
        $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-studentPassword").live("blur", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
    var studentPassword = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(studentPassword != "") {
        var passwordReg = /^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$/;
        if(!passwordReg.test($(this).val())) {
            $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Password must be at least 8 characters");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");

        }
        else {
            $("#signUp-studentPasswordRepeat").addClass("invalid");
            $("#signUp-studentPasswordRepeat").closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
            $("#signUp-studentPasswordRepeat").css("background-color", "white");
            var studentPasswordRepeat = $("#signUp-studentPasswordRepeat").val();
            if (studentPassword != studentPasswordRepeat) {
                $("#signUp-studentPasswordRepeat").closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Passwords do not match");
                $("#signUp-studentPasswordRepeat").css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
            }
            $(this).removeClass("invalid");
        }
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-studentPasswordRepeat").live("blur", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
    var studentPasswordRepeat = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(studentPasswordRepeat != "") {
        var studentPassword = $("#signUp-studentPassword").val();
        if (studentPassword != studentPasswordRepeat) {
            $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Passwords do not match");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
        }
        else {
            $("#signUp-studentPasswordRepeat").removeClass("invalid");
        }
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-parentPassword").live("blur", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
    var parentPassword = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(parentPassword != "") {
        var passwordReg = /^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$/;
        if(!passwordReg.test($(this).val())) {
        $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Password must be at least 8 characters");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("invalid");
        }
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-parentPasswordRepeat").live("blur", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
    var parentPasswordRepeat = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(parentPasswordRepeat != "") {
        var parentPassword = $("#signUp-parentPassword").val();
        if (parentPassword != parentPasswordRepeat) {
            $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Passwords do not match");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
        }
        else {
            $("#signUp-parentPasswordRepeat").addClass("invalid");
            $("#signUp-parentPasswordRepeat").closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
            $("#signUp-parentPasswordRepeat").css("background-color", "white");
            var parentPasswordRepeat = $("#signUp-parentPasswordRepeat").val();
            if (parentPassword != parentPasswordRepeat) {
                $("#signUp-parentPasswordRepeat").closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Passwords do not match");
                $("#signUp-parentPasswordRepeat").css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
            }
            $("#signUp-parentPasswordRepeat").removeClass("invalid");
        }
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-parentFirstName").live("blur", function() {
    var parentFirstName = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(parentFirstName != "") {
        $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-parentLastName").live("blur", function() {
    var parentLastName = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(parentLastName != "") {
        $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});

$("#signUp-parentPhone").live("blur", function() {
    $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").empty();
    var parentPhone = $(this).val();
    $(this).addClass("invalid");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    if(parentPhone != "") {
        var phoneReg = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
        if(!phoneReg.test($(this).val())) {
            $(this).closest("tbody").find(".errorPlaceholder").text("Please enter a valid phone number");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("invalid");
        }
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ffcccc");
    }
});
```

**HTML of form**

```
<table class="signUpTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Email*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-studentEmail" placeholder="student email">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="errorPlaceholder"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Repeat Email*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-studentEmailRepeat" placeholder="repeat email">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="errorPlaceholder"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Password*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="password" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-studentPassword" placeholder="password">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="errorPlaceholder"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Repeat Password*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="password" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-studentPasswordRepeat" placeholder="repeat password">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="errorPlaceholder"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">First Name*</td>
        <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
            <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-studentFirstName" placeholder="first name">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Last Name*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-studentLastName" placeholder="last name">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Cell Phone*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-studentPhone" placeholder="cell phone">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="errorPlaceholder"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Phone Carrier</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="signUpTextbox" id="signUp-studentPhoneCarrier" placeholder="phone carrier">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr></hr></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="signUpInstructions">Your local address must be within the city of <?php echo $footerLocation; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Student Address*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-studentAddress1" placeholder="student address 1">
                <br />
                <input type="text" class="signUpTextbox" id="signUp-studentAddress2" placeholder="student address 2">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr></hr></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Parent Email*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-parentEmail" placeholder="parent email">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="errorPlaceholder"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Repeat Email*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-parentEmailRepeat" placeholder="repeat parent email">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="errorPlaceholder"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Permanent or Parent Address*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-parentAddress1" placeholder="parent address 1">
                <br />
                <input type="text" class="signUpTextbox" id="signUp-parentAddress2" placeholder="parent address 2">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">City*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-parentCity" placeholder="city">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">State*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-parentState" placeholder="state">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">Zip*</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="invalid signUpTextbox" id="signUp-parentZip" placeholder="zip">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="signUpInstructions">Parents use their own email address and password to login to a linked account. We will email them details.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr></hr></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="signUpTextboxTitle">How did you head about us?</td>
            <td class="signUpTextboxCell">
                <input type="text" class="signUpTextbox" id="signUp-referral" placeholder="referral">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr></hr></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="signUpInstructions">*required</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type = "submit"  class = "toolbarButton footerMiddleAlignRight" id = "signUp-submit" value = "Sign Up"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="signUpError"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type = "text" class = "hiddenInput" id = "signUp-customerType" value = "<?php echo $customerType; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type = "text" class = "hiddenInput" id = "signUp-school" value = "<?php echo $school; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The validation error is shown if an element has the `.invalid` class. Are you 100% sure you remove that class when the user corrects something?

Comment: @sverri Yes, if you look at the individual validations, you can see that every time a input blurs, it checks again, and removes it when valid.  If it wasn't valid, the input should be highlighting red and displaying an error below the input.  But, I get no errors below the input, only at the bottom of the page.  It should be impossible to have an error at the bottom but none below inputs.  This line is included in all individual validations when the input is valid: $(this).removeClass("invalid");

Comment: @sverri Also, after clicking submit, the invalid inputs should go red if they are not already red.  See this line: $(".invalid").css("background-color", "#ffcccc");

Comment: What browsers are the affected users using?

Comment: @firefoxuser_1 the majority (by far) of my customers have said they are using chrome, but I have gotten a couple people using safari...I have no problems when testing it in any browser across 4 different computers, and have maxed out my gchat list asking people to check it in chrome (nobody has any problems)

Comment: It's possible there are errors, but the background color isn't changing for some reason. You should just be able to put the background color in the .invalid class on your css anyway.

Comment: @firefoxuser_1 That's a great idea, just in case the js isn't firing correctly, I will add this so that hopefully my users can give me more information when they call in

Comment: @firefoxuser_1 I just realized that I can't do this because my inputs start as "invalid" and I don't want them to all appear red before the customers have a chance to fill them out.  That's why I didn't use a css class originally.

Comment: Can you also post the code for the first login system? Since the error occurs in both, the problem must be in something that is shared between the two.

Comment: @firefoxuser_1 That's a great point.  That version is on an older hard drive from my last computer.  When I get home from work later I can dig it up and post it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hypothesis: most of the `blur` handlers remove the `invalid` class from their elements "immediately" (i.e., synchronously within the event handler).  But there's one that doesn't: the `#signUp-studentEmail` handler launches a POST request and only removes `invalid` in the AJAX success function.  If the user clicks Sign Up quickly after editing their email address (before that AJAX completes), the order of events may look like this:

1. `click` handler runs, sees `invalid` on the email textbox, reports the error.
2. AJAX completes, clears `invalid` from the textbox.

Thus the user would see an error, but no textboxes would be red.

If you can't reproduce this simply by editing the email field last and then clicking Sign Up, it may help to add a delay to the AJAX - either by delaying its launch with `setTimeout`, or by adding a delay to `signUpValidateEmail.php` on the server.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in getting back to you!  Around 3am, I decided to go to bed.  This makes a TON of sense to me, or at least is the most logical suggestion.  I will test this using the delay and post results this afternoon. If the setTimeourt proves you are right, I should be able to pull the emails when the form initially loads and put them in an object.  If I loop through the object, I shouldn't get any delays from the server.  Thank you SO SO much for the suggestion, I really appreciate the time you put into thinking about my long post.

Comment: so, after playing with setTimeout a bit, I was able to force the form to error within the time limit.  That being said, it did properly highlight the textbox red to notify me of where the form was generating the error.  Interestingly, as the setTimeout ran out, the background never got switched back to white.  I think you are still on to something with this answer, so I am going to make the fixes.  Monday will be a busy day for business, so I will know whether or not this solution worked at that point

Comment: Thank you for your patience while I tested your solution.  Unfortunately, I do not think this is what is causing the issue.  One of the ways I decided to test this was to email myself with an snapshot of the html at (but just prior to) submission, so I could see which inputs were marked "invalid".  Though there was seemingly no pattern to what was marked as invalid, I was able to verify that multiple inputs are causing the problem, not simply the studentEmail input.  See my edits for additional progress